# Codeigniter 2.2.2 / How to print the array data in a "View" which is passed in from a controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am not receiving any of the "country" data that I am passing from my controller to my view.  Here is my controller:

```
    public function country_destination()
{

    $this->load->model('model_admin');
    //Calling the get_unique_states() function to get the arr of state. Model already loaded.
    $arrCountries = $this->model_admin->get_unique_countries();

    //Getting the final array in the form which I will be using for the form helper to create a dropdown.
    foreach ($arrCountries as $countries) {
        $arrFinal[$countries->country] = $countries->country;
    }
    $data['countries'] = $arrFinal;

            // Basis page data
            $data = array(
                'templateVersion'   => 'template1',
                'headerVersion'     => 'header1',
                'css'               => '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/index.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                                       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lib/animate.css" media="screen, projection" />',
                'navBarVersion'     => 'navbar1',
                'main_content'      => 'detail-wrap/admin/country_destination', 
                'page_title'        => 'example.com - App',
                'footerVersion'     => 'footer1'
                );
            //echo "here";
            $this->load->view('detail-wrap/includes/template1', $data);      
}
```

In my view, I would like to dump the contents of $data which includes $data[countries].  This will help me determine if indeed 'some' data is being passed and aid with further debugging.

I have tried print_r($data); but I get an 'undefined variable: data' error.

Comment: you should check the extract() php function this way will get better understanding on what is been done in the background http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** the `$data` array's keys are converted into variables

You have to do

```
print_r($countries);  //to print the countries
```

in your view

You have to give some `key` to this array

```
 $data['somekey'] = array(
                'templateVersion'   => 'template1',
                'headerVersion'     => 'header1',
                'css'               => '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/index.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                                       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lib/animate.css" media="screen, projection" />',
                'navBarVersion'     => 'navbar1',
                'main_content'      => 'detail-wrap/admin/country_destination', 
                'page_title'        => 'example.com - App',
                'footerVersion'     => 'footer1'
                );
```

And access this data in the view with the help of the key. CI send the key as a normal php variable to the `view`

So from view you can access as `print_r($somekey)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies which now makes sense, however, is there a single comments to print everything in $data?

Answer (score 0):

In your view file you can write like this to show the array data in structured format.

```
echo "<pre>";

print_r($countries);
```